# The appendchild function cannot be executed successfully

Tags: javascript

The appendchild function cannot be executed successfully
Hello everyone:
I am making a web game, but in the process of making
An execution error occurred
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute'appendChild' on'Node': parameter 1 is not of type'Node'.
At line 37 of index.js
I have tried many times and have not been able to successfully solve this problem

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Flop memory game</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="game"></div>
   <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

css:

```
//The card picture is defined as a background picture
body{
    margin: 30px 0;
}
.card{
    margin: 10px;
    background-size: contain;//The length, width, and height of the card itself remain unchanged, and the length, width, and height are displayed completely, leaving blank areas
    background-repeat: no-repeat;//The card pictures are not repeated, to avoid all 6 cards showing the same card picture
    background-position:center center;//The position of the card is positioned in the middle of the web page background
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;

}
.card2{ //Use the createElement function in javaspript to add the undefined tag name section tag attribute on the new web page,
  Name card2, and then use appendChild function to put card2 into the tag element of the webpage div (game)
max-width: 920px;//Set the maximum width image allowable value
margin:0px auto;
display: flex;//Declare the classification attribute label of the outer container (such as the whole of 8 cards)
flex-wrap:wrap;//Set to wrap means that the card element is set to display in multiple lines to avoid the card from being displayed to the end
justify-content: space-evenly;//Arrange each card element evenly, the first card is placed at the starting point, and the last card element is placed at the end
}
```

javaspript

```
let cardarray=[
    {
        name:"a1",
        img:"img/a1.jpg",
    },
    {
        name:"a2",
        img:"img/a2.jpg",
    },
    {
        name:"a3",
        img:"img/a3.jpg",
    },
    {
        name:"a4",
        img:"img/a4.jpg",
    },
    {
        name:"a5",
        img:"img/a5.jpg",

    },
   {
       name:"a6",
       img:"img/a6.jpg",

   },
]//Add a card storage array and name it cardarray to store 6 card pictures
/*
Note: Javaspript allows to use the setAttribute function to add undefined tags to the html of the website, which means that the html tags are actually undefined.
Although there is no website attribute tag established by the setAttribute function in the syntax of the web page, it still exists, but it is an undefined html tag
*/
let game=document.getElementById("game");//Put the Javaspript of the web game into the div(game) of the webpage in a modular way
let card2=document.createElement("section");//Add an undefined label section on the webpage
card2.setAttribute("class","card2");/*Continue to the previous line, define the section label attribute as class and name as card2
                                     To enable access to all the function settings contained in the css file name card2 */
game.appendChild(card2);//Put the element whose section tag name is card2 into the tag element of the div(game) of the webpage


cardarray.forEach(element => {//Display each card image on the web page through an array, and the range of the number of cards is the 6 card images stored in the cardarray array
    let card=document.getElementById("div")//Define the attributes of each card as a div tag
    card.classList.add(card)//Set all the functions contained in the card name in the css file to each card in the cardarray
    card.dataset.name=intem.name//For each card generated by the array, the image of the card refers to the (img) image directory location of the cardarray array
    card.style.backgroundImage=item.img//Each card generated by the array, its name refers to the (name) name defined by the cardcarray array
    card2.appendChild(card)//
});
```

Comment: `game.appendChild("card2")` -> `game.appendChild(card2)` and `card2.appendChild("card")` -> `card2.appendChild(card)`

Comment: May I ask you again?  @Imran Rafiq Rather
After I finished the modification, it appeared again
Error message
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property'classList' of null
     at index.js:42
     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
     at index.js:40
(anonymous) @ index.js:42
(anonymous) @ index.js:40

Thank you!!

Comment: Let me code it on my machine and fix it...Don't worry Mate :)

Comment: Just want to know one thing :) Are the comments that you have used here in CSS file. Have you used those comments in your CSS as well. If yes then remove all your Comments from the CSS file :) In CSS we use /* --- */ as comments :)

Comment: The reason why my css uses comments is
In order to make changes easily in the future

Comment: I mean this is not the right way to add comments in CSS. They work in SCSS, but not in pure CSS... BY the way I found where the problem is working on that. It's this line   let card=document.getElementById("div")/

Comment: It's Done...I will update the answer and share the link

Comment: Please check the updated Code :) It's working... Now Only the images are in your own folder so they will work fine on your system. Do Accept the Answer and Vote if this helps :)

Comment: I got it!!
thanks for your help!!

Comment: You are welcome :) Hope you understood where the issue was ! Need any help in Front End Development. Just write a message and I will help provided I am not busy with work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Main reason why you are getting the error is because of this line of code.

`let card=document.getElementById("div")`

Because you have no element with the `id="div"` in the Code created by Javascript. That's why you are getting the error message.

Besides this, you are using a string `"card2"` and string `"card"` in you `appendChild()` function.

You need to use variable names as they are `card2` and `card` in the below code:
There is also a Typo here

```
cardarray=forEach()
```

This should be `cardarray.forEach()`.

And the logic to show cards within you section element needs to change also. I have modified your code to handle all the scenarios.

**Here is the codepen link:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/NWRYawQ

**FULL Working Code:**

```js
let cardarray=[
    {
        name:"a1",
        img:"img/a1.jpg",
    },
    {
        name:"a2",
        img:"img/a2.jpg",
    },
    {
        name:"a3",
        img:"img/a3.jpg",
    },
    {
        name:"a4",
        img:"img/a4.jpg",
    },
    {
        name:"a5",
        img:"img/a5.jpg",

    },
   {
       name:"a6",
       img:"img/a6.jpg",

   },
]
let game=document.getElementById("game");
let card2=document.createElement("section");
card2.className = "card2"
// card2.setAttribute("class","card2");
game.appendChild(card2);



cardarray.forEach(cardItem=>{
  const card = document.createElement("div");
  card.className = "card";
  card.textContent = cardItem.name;
  card.style.background = `url(${cardItem.img})`
  card2.appendChild(card);
  
})
```

```css
body{
    margin: 30px 0;
}
.card{
    margin: 10px;
  background:orange;
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
    height: 150px;
    width: 200px;
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
.card2{ 
width: 920px;
 min-height:300px;
  margin:0px auto;
  border:1px solid green;
display: flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
justify-content: space-evenly;
  background:teal;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
     <title>Flop memory game</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
   <div id="game"></div>
 
   <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```